# Google Sheets Index Match Not Found

Tags: google-sheets, match, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

Working on a spreadsheet to list inventory items for sale in bulk. Wanting it to automatically generate a "Condition Note" for each item based on it's SKU and Category.

Have a sheet named "Description Table" that has Condition Notes arranged by Category (row) and Condition (column.) The last 2 digits of the item's SKU determine its condition.

This is the formula I have so far, but it's giving an error that it's not finding the row in the MATCH evaluation, specifically "Did not find value '43' in MATCH evaluation." 43 is located in A6 of the Description Table sheet. Any ideas?

```
=INDEX('Description Table'!A1:J23,MATCH(RIGHT(C2,2),'Description Table'!A:A,0),MATCH(B2,'Description Table'!1:1,0))
```

Here's the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SBtJicsKlxykBfKwwLyeHV__ope-D1lciA8X2FD3CKo/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't match the string "43" with the number 43. You need to convert the string to a number:

```
=INDEX('Description Table'!A1:J23,MATCH(value(RIGHT(C2,2)),'Description Table'!A:A,0),MATCH(B2,'Description Table'!1:1,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I had verified the numbers in the table were registering as values, and had tried converting to a value to see if that was the issue, but I was trying to convert to a value AFTER matching.... It was a long night.

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(RIGHT(C2:C, 2)*1, 'Description Table'!A3:K, 
 MATCH(B2:B, 'Description Table'!A1:K1, 0), 0)))
```

[image: 0]